# On Google Sheets or Excel, if a column takes values from another sheet, how do I make new values go into a new, empty row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column (column X) in a table on a Google Sheet (Sheet B) which gets all its values from another sheet (Sheet A). The rest of the table just has normal human entry cells.

On Sheet A new values can be entered on any part of the sheet, not just the bottom, so new values in Sheet A don't always go to the bottom of column X in Sheet B - they go into the middle of column X, moving the below column X values down one cell each, throwing column X out of sync with the rest of the table.

I would like to know how, whenever there's a new value in Sheet A, there can be a new row in the Sheet B table with the new value in Column X and the rest of the row blank, so the cells that were next to each other in the Sheet B table can still stay next to each other.

Eg Say the Sheet B table looks like this

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Honda            Woowoo Yrkstrom
Mini             Chairrgr nee
Toyota           Frof Prog
```

If "Fiat" is added to the middle of Sheet A so will go in the middle of column X (this could happen whether column X is sorted or not), I would like the table to look like

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Fiat
Honda            Woowoo Yrkstrom
Mini             Chairrgr nee
Toyota           Frof Prog
```

NOT LIKE THE BELOW:

```
Column X:        Column Y:
Audi             Jibjab Jabjib
Fiat             Woowoo Yrkstrom
Honda            Chairrgr nee
Mini             Frof Prog
Toyota
```

How is this possible? I will accept any solution at all.

Thanks,
Milan

Comment: Can you share the sheet publicly and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Kessy I've just tried thinking about it for a while, but I think it would require some kind of Sheets scripting which I don't know anything about. I'm a Sheets newbie. Changing the position of cells in the same row together is something you can do manually when you highlight a table and sort, I just want the computer to do that same thing automatically - when it creates a new value in the column X and shifts the cells below down one, just shift the corresponding cells in column Y down one too.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ohm4nukHKWei5UJ06uaUE2btaEDcWTqAFhDtdqy2YDo/edit?usp=sharing shared what I can, Sheet A is the second sheet (with values in columns G K N Q T... put into Sheet B) and Sheet B is the third sheet

Answer (score 0):

See [testSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17EGADCWol5MOvxmzImgPLPPkSdd7k21IboobmKfeDI4/edit#gid=323237339)

Simple solution to use third sheet - SheetC which takes all data from SheetA and VLOOKUPs values from SheetB.

However, you'll have to add new items from SheetC to SheetB and put values manually.

Comment: @Milan That is exactly what I said in your previous question. Will you accept that now?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for your answer but in my case I can't add the items to Sheet B manually, there are too many, any more complex solution that's automatic?

Comment: @teylyn Thanks for writing that answer it was very educational, personally I don't understand why it's "not right" to do even this question, but it seems like it might not be possible to do this automatically